# UNIX not redirecting SQR errors to log file

Tags: oracle, unix, redirect, sqr

My code is not writing my error to program_error.log and I am unsure why. I intentionally have an on-select error and it is not getting displayed in program_error.log

```
#Include <strings.h>
sqr program.sqr -printer:hp $password >> program.log 2> program_errors.log
```

Comment: Is it going into `program.log`? Cross-platform tools don't necessarily handle stdout and stderr the way you might expect.

Comment: the error is  indeed printed in program.log